# How to align points from CSV import?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to import a CSV file but cant seem to align the points. I made sure the csv is in UTF-8 and using the project projection but cant seem to align the points no matter after trying multiple projections. What am I missing here?
[image]

Comment: Your coordinates are clearly not in EPSG:4326. You need to define the correct CRS at "Geometry CRS" within "Geometry Definition".

Comment: Thanks MrX but I have tried multiple projections and have yet to get them to align. How does one figure this out which projection is the correct one without aimlessly selecting several projections.

Comment: Best way is to ask the one you got the file from or looking at metadata if available. If that is not an option you can try onlineservices like http://projfinder.com/